# How to check if there are duplicates in a slice?

Tags: rust

Is there a native way to check if a slice has duplicates? For now, I use this:

```
fn has_dup<T: PartialEq>(slice: &[T]) -> bool {
    for i in 1..slice.len() {
        if slice[i..].contains(&slice[i - 1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    false
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(has_dup(&[1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 6]), true);
    assert_eq!(has_dup(&[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), false);
}
```

but for this kind of basic operations, I do not like to use hand-made code.

If there is no available function to do this in the standard library, is it a way to optimize my code? I know that indexing the slice is not the most optimized way (`for i in slice {}` vs `for i in 0..slice.len() { slice[i] }`).

Comment: This is basically the [Element distinctness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem). There are more efficient ways to do it than checking every element against the rest of the list, which is `O(n^2)`, but none of these are implemented in std. However, the trade-off is that they might require more memory.  See an approach to [removing dupes with a HashSet](https://github.com/Hoverbear/rust-rosetta/blob/master/tasks/remove-duplicate-elements/src/main.rs) on rosetta-code. It's to remove vs just check but it should give you an idea of how it can be done.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella This is strange that such a basic algorithm is not in the std.

Comment: @Boiethios why do you believe that this is a "basic" algorithm? Even if it is, remember that things like *random number generation*, which many people consider "basic", are provided by a crate.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In terms of algorithmic complexity, it is often better to keep track of unique values in an index. If you can check equality with `Hash` and `Eq`, you can try this utility function:

```
fn has_unique_elements<T>(iter: T) -> bool
where
    T: IntoIterator,
    T::Item: Eq + Hash,
{
    let mut uniq = HashSet::new();
    iter.into_iter().all(move |x| uniq.insert(x))
}

assert!(!has_unique_elements(vec![10, 20, 30, 10, 50]));
assert!(has_unique_elements(vec![10, 20, 30, 40, 50]));
assert!(has_unique_elements(Vec::<u8>::new()));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f16ecd16f4048abe5ec79ae6daf76bd5&version=stable)

Likewise, if your elements don't implement `Hash` but do implement [`Ord`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html), you can use a [`BTreeSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html) instead ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=634c7911c13ff96a3a63a756e083beea&version=stable)).

Comment: I like this solution, but there are more constraints on the type (`Hash` + `Clone`)

Comment: Can't make an omelette without breaking eggs. :P Either a hash function or a total order relation is required for faster look-ups. I'm not sure whether making copies of the previously fetched items can be avoided.

Comment: Is it possible to use `.cloned().all(move |x| uniq.insert(x))`?. The `ExactSizeIterator` constraint should not be needed.

Comment: Why yes, that's a nice improvement (you don't even need to clone the iterator). It's updated now.

Comment: `cloned` (with a `d`) does not clone the iterator but lazily clone each item while iterating.

Comment: @Boiethios: Note about `Clone`, if you call this method on `&Vec`, then you get an iterator of *references* which are cloneable by default. I think it'll be pretty rare to be calling this by value.

Comment: `move` isn't needed anymore it is?

Answer (score 13):

Indexing is not less optimized, it's just not idiomatic *in the presence of an iterator solution*. There is no iterator solution, so your code is already the optimal solution.

If you want to go down a more functional road, you can write

```
(1..slice.len()).any(|i| slice[i..].contains(&slice[i - 1]))
```

Comment: Indexing checks if the index is in the bounds. So there is a (small) overhead. But this small overhead can make a greater difference in a loop.

Comment: LLVM will take care of such simple loops. You are correct in the general case though.

Answer (score 0):

Besides checking for a duplicate, this solution allows to pass a custom compare function and returns the first occurrence. The use case is for smaller slices where `O(n^2)` time complexity is not an issue.

```
fn find_in_slice<T>(slice: &[T],
                    predicate: impl Fn(&T, &T) -> bool) -> Option<(usize, &T)>
{
    slice
        .iter()
        .enumerate()
        .find_map(|(i,v1)| slice[i+1..]
                  .iter()
                  .find(|v2| predicate(v1, v2))
                  .and_then(|v| Some((i, v))))
}

fn find_dup<T: std::cmp::PartialEq>(slice: &[T]) -> Option<(usize, &T)> {
    find_in_slice(slice, |v1, v2| v1 == v2)
}

fn main() {
    struct Item<'a> {
        name: &'a str,
    }
    assert_eq!(find_dup(&[0, 1, 2, 2, 3]), Some((2, &2)));
    assert_eq!(find_dup(&[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), None);
    assert_eq!(find_dup(&["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "x", "beta"]), Some((1, &"beta")));
    let (idx, val) = find_in_slice(&[Item{name: "foo"}, Item{name: "bar"}, Item{name: "foo"}],
                             |v1, v2| v1.name == v2.name).unwrap();
    assert_eq!((idx, val.name), (0, "foo"));
```

Answer (score -5):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub fn _contains_duplicate(vec: &Vec<usize>) -> bool {
    let mut map = HashMap::<usize, usize>::new();
    for (i, num) in vec.iter().enumerate() {
        match map.contains_key(num) {
            true => return true,
            false => map.insert(*num, i),
        };
    }
    false
}
```

Comment: (a) An answer with code only is usually not good. Some explanation will help. (b) You're not generic and the OP is. (c): You never use the value, only the key, so a hashset is better. (d) and worst: There is already an accepted answer that fixes all of those. Your answer adds nothing.

Comment: HashSet current implementation in Rust standard library uses an HashMap, and checks keys unicity at insert operation. Constructor is `pub struct HashSet<T, S = DefaultHashBuilder, A: Allocator + Clone = Global> { pub(crate) map: HashMap<T, (), S, A>, }`