# How to check if a collection of structs has duplicate values in the fields?

Tags: vector, struct, rust, duplicates

I want to extract some data from a vector from some structs in order to check if there are duplicates

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    id: i32,
    name: String
}

fn main() {
    let test1 = Test { id: 1, name: String::from("one") };
    let test2 = Test { id: 2, name: String::from("two") };
    let test3 = Test{ id: 3, name: String::from("one") };
    
    let mut small_collection = Vec::new();
    small_collection.push(test1);
    small_collection.push(test2);
    small_collection.push(test3);
    
     let uniques: Vec<String> = small_collection.iter()
        .map(|x| x.name.as_str())
        .collect();

    // let num_dups = clients.len() - uniques.len();
}
```

The program creates a `small_collection` of structs. However I want to check, after the creation of the vector, if there are duplicates in the `Test.name` field.

So I am trying to iterate and create a new `Vector<String>`. If the `len()` for my collections and the reduced names is the same, then there is no duplicates. In this case the value "one" appears twice.

However I am stuck, any help?

Comment: Hi there - does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766560/how-to-check-if-there-are-duplicates-in-a-slice answer the question? A slice is a slight abstraction on a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce a `Vec` to only unique values by calling [`sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort) and then [`dedup`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.dedup) on the `Vec` like so:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    id: i32,
    name: String
}

fn main() {
    let test1 = Test { id: 1, name: String::from("one") };
    let test2 = Test { id: 2, name: String::from("two") };
    let test3 = Test { id: 3, name: String::from("one") };

    let mut small_collection = Vec::new();
    small_collection.push(test1);
    small_collection.push(test2);
    small_collection.push(test3);

    let mut uniques: Vec<&str> = small_collection.iter()
        .map(|x| x.name.as_str())
        .collect();

    uniques.sort();
    uniques.dedup();

    let num_dups = small_collection.len() - uniques.len();
    assert_eq!(num_dups, 1);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4bdbbeebb802ba30ba0902107922206c)

You can turn it into a one-liner by collecting into a [`HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) (which does not store duplicates by default):

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Test {
    id: i32,
    name: String
}

fn main() {
    let test1 = Test { id: 1, name: String::from("one") };
    let test2 = Test { id: 2, name: String::from("two") };
    let test3 = Test { id: 3, name: String::from("one") };

    let mut small_collection = Vec::new();
    small_collection.push(test1);
    small_collection.push(test2);
    small_collection.push(test3);

    let uniques_len = small_collection.iter()
        .map(|x| x.name.as_str())
        .collect::<HashSet<&str>>()
        .len();

    let num_dups = small_collection.len() - uniques_len;
    assert_eq!(num_dups, 1);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=286e87395181e85439963a65a2c4270c)